# Submit form from content script of a Chrome extension

Tags: html, jquery, forms, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am creating an extension that fills a form and submits it. The extension is able to fill the form inputs but gives the following error when triggers the submit event on the form.

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

I am doing this from a content script using the following code.

```
var form = $('<Query selector for form>');
form.submit();
```

Following are the manifest file contents:

```
{
    "name": "My Extenssion",
    "description": "My extension description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs", "background", "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage", "activeTab", "scripting"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [ "jquery-3.6.0.min.js", "aes.js", "content.js" ]
      }
    ],
}
```